# Communicate with SQL Server 2008 R2 through Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I have an SQL server configured with a Server in Hyper-V and I am trying to access the database through the Host computer. When I ping the SQL server (static IP) they communicate and vice versa. Then through the SQL configuration manager, I can access the database from SQL server, but not from the host computer (gives me an error 40 and error 5).

I've configured the TCP/IP of the SQL configuration manager to match the SQL server's IP address. I've set the port number to 1433. Is there anything else I've missed?

Comment: Firewall on the guest.

Comment: @Dave We have another SQL server that I tried replicating the settings and on that working server, we don't have named pipes enabled, but when I do enable it, I get a runtime error. Also where do I edit the connection string? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It was the public network firewall. I disabled it on the guest machine and all is working now. I did add an exception on the firewall for the program but apparently that was not enough. Thanks!